# WebEelement.getText() is not fetching the text which is after the '/' symbol

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to verify the text visible on the screen by comparing the text which I got from the `WebElement.getText()` function with the expected text.

But the `getText()` function is returning only partial text that is the the text after '/' is not available hence the test is failing, however on the screen the whole text is visible.

Element:

```
<div class="header-bc-item ip-address ip-address-active"><svg><path>....
</path></svg>Text / 10.206.248.27:5000</div>
```

XPath:

```
By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'"+str+"')]
```

Comment: Can you show us, how html look?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML and your code trials

Comment: Did you get this xpath by inspecting the HTML element? I think better to use the one suggest in the browser.

Comment: Edit your question and post the code you are using to get this text. Your locator is incomplete and this should work just fine. My guess is that something else is wrong or you are looking at it in some app, etc that is treating the `/` like an escape character instead of plain text.

Answer (score 0):

I tried changing the xpath used to identify the web element and it worked for me.

since I was using the text itself to identify the web element,would be the cause for this issue.